# Modern alternative for pam_userdb (for use with vsftpd)

Tags: pam, vsftpd, bcrypt

Quite some years ago, I setup a vsftpd server with virtual users, according to some howtos (still) to be found on the internet, using pam_userdb.

Like this: A file called `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd.virtual`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users crypt=crypt
account required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users crypt=crypt
session required pam_loginuid.so
```

A setting inside `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

```
pam_service_name=vsftpd.virtual
```

And a BerkeleyDB containing the user and password hashes (`/etc/vsftpd/users.db`).

According to the manpage of `pam_userdb`, this module only supports clear-text passwords or `crypt`ed ones, always in a BerkeleyDB.

Meanwhile, this approach seems both dated and impractical to me, as plain `crypt`ed passwords are insecure (not even speaking of the clear text variant), and the handling of a BerkeleyDB containing them makes using some wrapper necessary.

So: **Is there some alternative PAM module that e.g. can handle a plain text file with users and `bcrypt`ed passwords?** Or at least with passwords using some SHA hash? That can be updated using e.g. `htpasswd` (or `mkpasswd`)? Something like a Dovecot users file, or an htaccess file for use with e.g. Lighttpd?

Something like

```
some_user:$2y$05$ensqtXGZXUf5DQosKk51.utplrWUqkeZzNNI8.lCVT.K86uillL4a
```

? I suppose some other PAM module could be used by vsftpd in the same way? Thanks for all help!

Comment: FTP is at least as dated as `pam_userdb`...

Comment: Which does not really answer the question very well.